# How to make a trigger that will not allow duplicate data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

It is necessary to make the addition of a unique line in what ever field.
I write this:

```
alter trigger Triger1
on Week_Schedule for insert
as
    if @@ROWCOUNT=1
begin
    if exists (
        select *
        from inserted as i, Week_Schedule as w
        where i.Week_Number = w.Week_Number 
    )
    begin
        rollback tran
        print 'Week number already exists!'
    end
end
```

but something goes wrong. By adding even a unique line pops up a warning with the text of my trigger. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why not a unique constraint instead?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: It is necessary to make it a trigger)

Comment: @СергейПолынцев . . . You should clarify what you mean by "unique line".  I'm interpreting it as "another line".

Comment: **Why** is it necessary to use a trigger? You have the most simple of built in constructs that handles this elegantly and efficiently, not using it is just madness - `ALTER TABLE dbo.Week_Schedule ADD CONSTRAINT UQ__Week_Schedule__Week_number UNIQUE (Week_number)`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to check `@@ROWCOUNT`.  You have written the logic correctly using `inserted`, so you don't need some weird work-around like that.

If I understand correctly, just enclose the body of the trigger in a `begin`/`end` block:

```
alter trigger Triger1
on Week_Schedule for insert
as
begin
    if exists (select 1
               from inserted i join
                    Week_Schedule w
                    on i.Week_Number = w.Week_Number 
             )
    begin
        rollback tran
        print 'Неделя с таким номером уже существует!'
    end;
end;
```

Then you can add additional statements in the `begin`/`end` block.

EDIT:

As noted in a comment, the above will roll-back all inserts (as opposed to just those with a single row as in the original question).

I strongly suspect that the real solution to the OPs issue is some combination of foreign key, unique, and perhaps check constraints.  However, that would be an answer to *another* question, which I encourage the OP to ask.

Comment: I guarantee that this trigger will rollback every insert. It's a `for insert` trigger which means that every row in `inserted` is also present in the table itself. So we know that every row will match, at least with itself.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever . . . That is a good observation, true, of course, of the OP's original trigger as well . . . except when the OP is inserting multiple rows.

Comment: Just edit your answer and use `INSTEAD OF` trigger to handle the inserts...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you should consider a unique constraint for this.  Triggers can cause a lot of un-intended consequences and is un-necessary overhead for this particular case.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Week_Schedule 
ADD CONSTRAINT YOURCONSTRAINTNAMEHERE UNIQUE (Week_number)
```